# Is it possible to change "msg" and "srv" folder position in a package?

Tags: ros, msg, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I am working on a multi-framework environment I wanted to separate what is related to ROS from the other. I would like to put the "msg" and "srv" folder into ros/msg and ros/srv. Is there any Cmake variable to configure this ?

In the same way, I would like to customize the position of srv_gen and msg_gen, is there also a variable ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9809/is-it-possible-to-change-%22msg%22-and-%22srv%22-folder-position-in-a-package-?/) by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 352 on 2011-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-05-07**:
nobody knows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those locations are not configurable.

Unfortunately, the assumptions about where the message/service source files are and where the generated code goes are embedded in both `rosbuild` and in the code-generation logic in all the client libraries.  The `msg_gen` and `srv_gen` locations are further embedded in `rospack`, which looks for a file called `generated` in each of those directories to decide whether to add `msg_gen/cpp/include` and `srv_gen/cpp/include` to the compiler include path.

While all those assumptions in code could be made configurable, it would be a large, and largely untested, change.

If relocating those files is important to you, I recommend [requesting an enhancement in rosbuild2](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=rosbuild2&type=enhancement).  Be sure to describe your use case thoroughly so that we can understand what's needed, and judge the tradeoffs involved.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-05-08**:
thanks for this clear answer.  It is just a matter of folder organization and confort. It's as being able to configure the build bin or lib directory. As srv and msg are "sources" and msg_gen and srv_gen headers files, they coud go in my src or  include dirs. I am not sure this worth the changes